# Aggregate results by week and month for charts

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is there a way to convert daily values into weekly averages for charting?

Sample source sheet

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Data 1 | 1/1/2018 | 1/2/2018 | 1/3/2018 | etc...365 days |
---------------------------------------------------
| row 1  |    25    |   30     |    5     | etc...| 
---------------------------------------------------
| row 2  |    2     |          |    4     | etc...|
---------------------------------------------------
| etc ... each row has a different cadence.
```

Except for, each row may not have values daily, but rather weekly or monthly, depending on the cadence.  So I would like to use the query function to aggregate some rows as weeks, and some rows as the month.

Expected results
for a weekly aggregate (if there is more than 1 value I just want the avg for the week, IE: if in a week there are values: 2,3,3, simply show: 2)

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Data 1 | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | etc...52 weeks |
---------------------------------------------------
| row 1  |    25  |   30   |    5   | etc...| 
---------------------------------------------------
| row 2  |    2   |   0    |    4   | etc...|
---------------------------------------------------
| etc ...
```

for a monthly aggregate (if there is more than 1 value I just want the avg for the month, IE; if in a month there are values: 25,50,100, simply show: 58)

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Data 1 | Jan | Feb | Mar | etc...12 months |
---------------------------------------------------
| row 1  | 50  | 30  |  55 | etc...| 
---------------------------------------------------
| row 2  | 2   |  0  | 4   | etc...|
---------------------------------------------------
| etc ...
```

This way, I can create graphs showing the correct unit of measure (week, month, etc).  How could I convert?

Comment: 1. Google Sheets doesn't include a built-in way to do this. 2. The question is too broad and doesn't include a brief description of your search/research efforts

Comment: Related: [Google spreadsheet: reformat event data (several dates on one row/event) to create a .csv file (one date per row/event)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85437/88163)

Answer (score 2):

**for week:**


```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(QUERY(
 {ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(WEEKNUM($A$1:$AE$1, 2))),
  TRANSPOSE($A2:$AE2)},
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&COLUMN()&"'", 0)))), 0)
```

**for month:**


```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(QUERY(
 {ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MONTH($A$1:$AE$1))),
  TRANSPOSE($A2:$AE2)},
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&COLUMN()&"'", 0)))), 0)
```


[image: 3]